# How can a gauge field have physical effects if it only reflects a redundancy in our mathematical description of physical reality?

Tags: gauge-theory, classical-field-theory

I struggle to reconcile two aspects of classical gauge field theories, stated informally (and vaguely, I admit) as follows:

1. Changing the gauge **does not have any physical effects** because the freedom to choose a gauge only reflects a redundancy in the mathematical description of physical reality.
2. Gauge fields **do have a physical effect** because they induce interactions of matter fields. Interacting matter fields certainly behave differently than free matter fields.

**Question: how can a gauge field have physical effects if it only reflects a redundancy in our mathematical description of physical reality?** I appreciate answers which help to build physical intuition as well as more mathematically-minded answers.

More formally, let $\pi: P \rightarrow M$ be a principal $G$-bundle over spacetime $M$, and $F$ a vector space carrying a representation $\rho: G \rightarrow GL(F)$. A section of the associated bundle $\pi_F: P \times_G F$ represents a matter field. Here, $P \times_G F \equiv (P \times F)/\sim$, with
$$(p', f') \sim (p,f) \iff \exists g \in G: \left(p' = pg \wedge f' = \rho(g^{-1})f\right).$$
Thus, the points of $P \times_G F$ are equivalence classes $[p, f]$.

For concreteness, take $G = SO(d)$, $P$ the principal bundle of $d$-dimensional orthonormal frames, and $F = \mathbb{R}^d$, equipped with the obvious representation of $SO(d)$. Then a point $[p, f]$ of the associated bundle consists of all pairs of orthonormal frames $ \{ \mathbf{e}_i \} $ and $d$-tuples of real numbers $f^i$ which represent the same vector $f^i \mathbf{e}_i$.

Now, choosing a gauge amounts to picking one representative of $[p, f]$ in each fiber, and a gauge transformation amounts to picking another representative of the **same equivalence class**. The vectors in the associated bundle, and hence the matter field, are invariant under a gauge transformation. (The vector *components* $f^i$ are of course not invariant: their transformation just compensates the transformation of the frame.) This means in particular that two vectors in different fibers which were parallel before the gauge transformation will still be parallel after the gauge transformation, since both of them stay what they were (is this true?). Taking "infinitesimally close" fibers, this implies that also the derivative of the vector field is completely unimpressed by the gauge transformation, not only the vectors themselves.

**With this setup, I struggle to understand how gauge fields can have observable consequences, e.g., by inducing interactions**. In my understanding, gauge fields *somehow* (and here lies the source of my difficulties, probably) just encode a choice of gauge, after all.

Comment: Source for point 2? Note that point 1 is not in contradiction with "we do use gauge fields to formulate a theory which correctly models experiments".

Comment: @TobiasFünke "The crucial point is that connections (the gauge fields) define a covariant derivative on these associated vector bundles, leading to a coupling between gauge fields and matter fields (if the matter fields are charged, i.e. the vector bundles are associated to a non-trivial representation of the gauge group). In a gauge-invariant Lagrangian this results in terms of order
higher than two in the matter and gauge fields, which are interpreted as interactions between the corresponding particles." M. J. D. Hamilton, Mathematical Gauge Theory, Springer 2017.

Comment: Ok. As far as I understand the quote, it does not at all correspond to your point 2.

Comment: I'm no expert, but the sketch I had in my mind is that the gauge field can have no local physical significance, but it can have global significance. Only some field configurations are topologically permitted, and this fact can be detected by experiment (e.g. the aharanov bohm effect).

Answer (score 9):

You just need to phrase both your points more carefully. That changing the gauge has no physical effect does not mean the *gauge field* does not have any physical effect (for one, since not all possible configurations of the gauge field are connected by gauge transformations). Let's discuss this a bit more with the archetypal example of a Yang-Mills gauge theory: Electromagnetism with $\mathrm{U}(1)$ as its gauge group.

For the 4-potential (= gauge field = connection form) $A$, the physically relevant and gauge invariant observable associated with it is the field strength tensor (= curvature) $F = \mathrm{d}A$, whose individual components are the tradition electric and magnetic fields. These are certainly observable, and that $A$ carries a gauge symmetry $A\mapsto A +\mathrm{d}f$ has nothing to do with the meaningfulness of $F$.

The point is that describing the theory directly in terms of $F$ - or, indeed, the vector fields $E$ and $B$ - is not amenable to a nice Lagrangian formulation, while in terms of $A$ it is straightforward to write down the action
$$ S[A] = \int F\wedge {\star}F,$$
whose equations of motion together with the Bianchi identity $\mathrm{d}F = 0$ yields the classical Maxwell equations.

You couple this to a current $j$ of other fields simply by adding a term $A\wedge {\star}j$ in the Lagrangian, and this current, too, is gauge-invariant for $\mathrm{U}(1)$ as the gauge group - but it is not forbidden that the current itself is a function of gauge-variant fields $\psi(x)$ that are simply combined in a gauge-invariant way. And indeed this is the description of the electron via Dirac spinor fields, coupling the gauge-variant Dirac spinor fields $\psi(x)$ to the gauge field $A$ by replacing the ordinary derivative in the Dirac action by the covariant derivative with respect to $A$. This yields a three-way product of the form $\psi A \psi$, which is how a gauge field "mediates interaction" - in the quantum theory this will result in diagrams that represent an interaction between the fermions associated with $\psi$ and the bosons associated with $A$.

It is still true that $A$ is not observable and is invariant under gauge, but it still has two degrees of freedom left after eliminating the gauge symmetry, which correspond to the two possible polarizations of an electromagnetic wave, or, in the quantum theory, with the two possible helicity states of the photon.

The "redundancy" of the gauge symmetry is not total - there *is* information in all the gauge-variant objects that can be extracted in gauge-invariant form, such as the curvature or the conserved current, and it would be hard to formulate the theory as elegantly as a Lagrangian formulation without using the "redundant" gauge-variant fields as the basic dynamical variables of the theory.